# AngularJS: Radio buttons lost value after moving to next partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bunch of questions with Radio buttons as the options. Each question has a partial, whenever I move from one partial to another, I lose the value of the buttons except the most recent one. How do I fix this?

**Partial:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
<section class="myinfo">
   <center>
      <a href="#details/{{prevItem}}" class="button">PREV</a>
      <a href="#details/{{nextItem}}" class="button">NEXT</a>
   </center>
   <p class="sel">
       {{questions[currItem].q}}
   </p>
   <ul>
       <li class="optlist" ng-repeat="item in questions[currItem].opt">
           <label class="formgroup">
              <input type="radio" name="q" ng-click="store(item.pos, currItem)" value="{{item.pos}}" />
              <span>{{item.val}}</span>
           </label>
       </li>
   </ul>
   <p class="ques">You've chosen: {{selopt}}</p>
   <center>
      <a ng-click="show()">Check</a>
   </center>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('OneController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams' ,function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/JOSCO.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.questions = data;
    $scope.currItem= $routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
    if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
        $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) - 1;
    }
    else {
        $scope.prevItem = $scope.questions.length - 1;
    }

    if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.questions.length-1) {
        $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId) + 1;
    }
    else {
        $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }
  });
  $scope.ansArr = [];
  $scope.store = function(pos, index) {
    $scope.ansArr[index] = pos;
    alert($scope.ansArr[index]);
  };
  $scope.show = function() {
    $scope.s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      $scope.s = $scope.s + "  " + $scope.ansArr[i];
    }
    alert($scope.s); // returns undefined for everything except the last one
  };
}]);
```

Comment: You need to use a service to store the data. Each route change means a new instance of your controller and all scope is destroyed

Comment: what is `whichItem` and `currItem`? mean where it is defined?Can please be a little bit clearer what you are doing in store fuction?

Comment: Sorry, no such thing as which item. whichItem == currItem

Comment: As @charlietfl suggested you need to create a service where you would declare the `$scope.ansArr = []` and write store function there.As your route changes previous instances of scope should be undefined.Try something like `app.factory('SaveAnswers', function($http) {
    var ansArr = [];
    var service = {}; 
            
    service.store : function(pos, index) {
            ansArr[index] = pos;   
           
        }
    return service;
});
`

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a value to radio input you need to add **ng-model**:

```
<input type="radio" data-ng-model="item.pos"/>
```

Each time current route (in the same hierarchy) is changed then the previous controller destroyed and next controller created, therefore the value not saved between. You can use service as said, but also you can store the values in **$rootScope** rather then **$scope**, because its common to all app, so you earn shared data between transitions. Just **inject** **$rootScope** to your **controller** and use it: **$rootScope.anyValue = val;**

Comment: The value of `rootScope` is also lost whilst making the transition

Comment: depends how you use it, post the complete code and i'll be able to review it